# Regular Expression in JavaScript to allow only numbers with optional 2 decimals

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to write a regular expression in which allows

1. backspace
2. 0-9 digits
3. optional fractional part with two decimals (no limit on integral part how many digits there can be)

For example:

- Allowed lists is [12 , 232.0 ,  23.(with only dot)  , 345.09 , 78.23 ,   134.00  , 0.21  , .21  , .02 , .01 .12 ]
- Not allowed are [12.878 , 34.343.334 , .0003 ]

The use of this regular expression would be like on javascript event

```
<input type="text"  onKeyPress="validatenumber(event);"   /><br>
```

**My code is**

```
function validatenumber(evt) {
  var theEvent = evt || window.event;
  var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
  key = String.fromCharCode( key );
  var regex = /^[0-9\b]+$/;    // allow only numbers [0-9] 
  if( !regex.test(key) ) {
    theEvent.returnValue = false;
    if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

I want to change only this line with the new regex:

```
var regex = /^[0-9\b]+$/;    // allow only numbers [0-9]
```

Comment: What's with `.1` or `0.1` valid or not?

Comment: both .1 and 0.1 are allow

Answer (score 7, accepted):

find the final solution at least

```
<input id="txtId" type="text" onkeyup="NumAndTwoDecimals(event , this);"></input>
```

and the

```
 function NumAndTwoDecimals(e , field) {
    var val = field.value;
    var re = /^([0-9]+[\.]?[0-9]?[0-9]?|[0-9]+)$/g;
    var re1 = /^([0-9]+[\.]?[0-9]?[0-9]?|[0-9]+)/g;
    if (re.test(val)) {
        //do something here

    } else {
        val = re1.exec(val);
        if (val) {
            field.value = val[0];
        } else {
            field.value = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here it is:

```
/^\d*(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/
```

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qd7BL/

Comment: sir i will be very thankful to you if you give me working example with onkeypress. i mean if user press key other than allow character simply do nothing if allow write in textbox

Comment: mean with event validnum(event)

Comment: <input type="text"  onKeyPress="validatenumber(event);"   />


function validatenumber(evt) {
  var theEvent = evt || window.event;
  var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
  key = String.fromCharCode( key );
 var regex = /^[0-9]*(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/;
  if( !regex.test(key) ) {
    theEvent.returnValue = false;
    if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
  }
}


it works and allow backspace and numbers but not period(.)

Answer (score 0):

How about this regex:

```
^\d*(?:\.\d\d)?$
```

Comment: this matches an empty string

Comment: `function validatenumber(evt) {
  var theEvent = evt || window.event;
  var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
  key = String.fromCharCode( key ); 
 var regex =/^\d*(?:\.\d\d)?$/;
  if( !regex.test(key) ) {
    theEvent.returnValue = false;
    if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
  }
}`
`<input type="text"  onKeyPress="validatenumber(event);"   />`
@M42

Comment: @user3132930: OK for the code, but what values of `key` don't match?

Comment: @M42 values that does not match are [ period(.) ]

Comment: @user3132930: I don't get you. Please, give a **value** of `key` that doesn't match. The value `[ period(.) ]` you gave is not suppose to match unless I forget something.

Comment: the value of key is 190

Answer (score 0):

This below simple html code will validate the required value and also +ve & -ve numbers of atleast 1 digit additionally optional 2 digits after decimal point.

**JS Code:**

```
        function validateNum() {

            /*
            For mandatry input field, use variable: "patForReqdFld".
            For optional input filed, use variable: "patForOptFld".
            */

            var patForReqdFld = /^(\-)?([\d]+(?:\.\d{1,2})?)$/;
            var patForOptFld = /^(\-)?([\d]*(?:\.\d{1,2})?)$/;

            var value = document.getElementById('txtNum').value;

            if(patForReqdFld.test(value)) {
                alert('Valid Number: ' + value);
            } else {
                alert('Invalid Number: ' + value);
            }
        }
```

**HTML Code:**

```
        <label>Enter Number:&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtNum" onBlur="validateNum()"/>
```